# Why does exim use openssl from system instead of compiled version?

Tags: compiling, openssl, shared-library, exim

I try to upgrade from exim 4.84 to exim 4.94

My Local/Makefile for exim contains this:

```
SUPPORT_TLS=yes
TLS_LIBS=-L/MYPATH/lib/ -lssl -lcrypto -ldl
TLS_INCLUDE=-I/MYPATH/include/openssl/
USE_OPENSSL=yes
```

When I check the compiled binary in the build-Linux-x86_64 directory, I get this, which is fine, Compile OpenSSL matches Runtime OpenSSL:

```
$ build-Linux-x86_64/exim -d-all+acl --version
Exim version 4.94 #2 built 05-Jun-2020 13:15:11
Copyright (c) University of Cambridge, 1995 - 2018
(c) The Exim Maintainers and contributors in ACKNOWLEDGMENTS file, 2007 - 2018
Support for: crypteq iconv() OpenSSL DANE DKIM DNSSEC Event OCSP PIPE_CONNECT PRDR TCP_Fast_Open
Lookups (built-in): lsearch wildlsearch nwildlsearch iplsearch dbm dbmjz dbmnz dnsdb
Authenticators: cram_md5 plaintext
Routers: accept dnslookup ipliteral manualroute queryprogram redirect
Transports: appendfile autoreply pipe smtp
Fixed never_users: 0
Configure owner: 0:0
Size of off_t: 8
Compiler: GCC [4.9.2]
Library version: Glibc: Compile: 2.19
                        Runtime: 2.19
Library version: BDB: Compile: Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
                      Runtime: Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
Library version: OpenSSL: Compile: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
                          Runtime: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
                                 : built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
Library version: PCRE: Compile: 8.36
                       Runtime: 8.36 2014-09-26
```

However, after I install it with make install and check the final binary, I get this:

```
$ exim-4.94-2 -d-all+acl --version
Exim version 4.94 #2 built 05-Jun-2020 13:15:11
Copyright (c) University of Cambridge, 1995 - 2018
(c) The Exim Maintainers and contributors in ACKNOWLEDGMENTS file, 2007 - 2018
Support for: crypteq iconv() OpenSSL DANE DKIM DNSSEC Event OCSP PIPE_CONNECT PRDR TCP_Fast_Open
Lookups (built-in): lsearch wildlsearch nwildlsearch iplsearch dbm dbmjz dbmnz dnsdb
Authenticators: cram_md5 plaintext
Routers: accept dnslookup ipliteral manualroute queryprogram redirect
Transports: appendfile autoreply pipe smtp
Fixed never_users: 0
Configure owner: 0:0
Size of off_t: 8
Compiler: GCC [4.9.2]
Library version: Glibc: Compile: 2.19
                        Runtime: 2.19
Library version: BDB: Compile: Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
                      Runtime: Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
Library version: OpenSSL: Compile: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
                          Runtime: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
                                 : built on: Fri Mar  1 20:47:13 2019
Library version: PCRE: Compile: 8.36
                       Runtime: 8.36 2014-09-26
```

The runtime OpenSSL version is from the system and not what I have compiled.

Any ideas what went wrong here?

Edit:

I checked, both files are identical and when I copy the exim binary to a random directory (like /tmp) it shows the correct runtime. It is only in my bin directory where this happens

Comment: How did you install the OpenSSL you built? It looks like an OpenSSL installation issue. According to the [build documentation](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-4.90.1/doc/html/spec_html/ch-building_and_installing_exim.html): _If you want to build Exim with TLS support, you must first install either the OpenSSL or GnuTLS library. There is no cryptographic code in Exim itself for implementing SSL._

Comment: ./config --openssldir=/MYPATH  -fPIC no-gost enable-shared

Comment: What system is it? To check if you have a precompiled version you could use.

Answer (score 1):

Exim will use the system's shared libraries. They are loaded by the system at runtime, not by Exim. That's why the binary is the same.

So, if you want to use your locally compiled OpenSSL you have at least these three options (no special order):

- use LD_LIBRARY_PATH, pointing to your local OpenSSL build, before you run Exim. That will instruct the system loader to try get the shared libraries from that location first.
- compile Exim as an static binary, meaning that the binary will already have the OpenSSL library built in. No dynamic loading.
- install the OpenSSL you compiled to the system, so that it will be available system-wide.

Note that OpenSSL is a sensitive library that you will probably have fully updated at all times. Depending on your distribution, it might be a better idea to install a packaged version, so that you also get security updates.

Comment: I tried LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but even though the Runtime matches with  -d-all+acl --version, I get the same problems during production, probably/maybe because it spawns a subprocess where the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env gets lost (it has to be started by root and then runs as another user, so it is quite possible that env gets lost there)

Comment: Compiling a static binary (with "CFLAGS +=-static") doesn't work either, because I get undefined references to many pthread_* functions

Comment: After giving up and trying to compile with the OpenSSL from the system - that doesn't work either, I still get the same error when trying to send over smtp: T=remote_smtp defer (-1): smtp transport process returned non-zero status 0x7f00: exit code 127